# line 13 self.keys.append(key): TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation Что делать?

Tags: python

Вот код

```
class Keylogger:

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.keys = []

    def on_press(self, key):
        print(f"{key} pressed")
        self.keys.append(key):
        self.count += 1

        if self.count >= 10:
            self.write_file(self.keys)

    def on_release(self, key):
        if key == Key.esc:
            return False 

    def write_file(self, keys):
        with open("log.txt", "a" ) as file:
            for key in self.keys:
                k = str(key).replace("'", "")

                if.k.find("space") > 0:
                    file.write("\n") 
                elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                    fil.write(k)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    obj = Keylogger()
    with Listener(on_press = obj.on_press, on_release = obj.on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Comment: Переписать весь код, убедившись, что ни в одном блоке не смешаны пробелы с табами. Должны быть или только пробелы, или только табы (по возможности настроить редактор, чтобы при нажатии tab, вставил 4 пробела вместо него).

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Там не только в этом проблема, сплошные нубские опечатки кругом :/

Answer (score 1):

А что в этой строке делает двоеточие в конце строки?

```
self.keys.append(key):
```

У меня другую ошибку интерпретатор показывает, но в той же строке. Уберите двоеточие для начала.

Также ошибка есть в этой строке:

```
if.k.find("space") > 0:
```

Точка после `if` явно лишняя, на неё тоже будет ругаться интерпретатор.